# Dock.Left/Right breaks simple docking based layout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout

This is yet another Windows Forms (stupid?) question about layout.

The desired layout is pretty simple:

- Form

  - ListBox (Dock.Fill)
  - Panel (Dock.Bottom)

    - Button (Dock.Right)

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(new ListBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });

        Panel panel = new Panel { AutoSize = true, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
        panel.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "X", Dock = DockStyle.Right });

        this.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
}
```

Here is the expected result:

```
+----------+
|          |
| ListBox  |
|          |
|          |
+----------+
+----------+
|  Panel   |
|     +---+|
|     | X ||
|     +---+|
+----------+
```

The issue is that if I `Dock.Left` or `Dock.Right` the button the `Panel` shrinks and disappears with the `Button`:

[image]

But with `Dock.Top` or `Dock.Bottom` the `Button` and the `Panel` appear as expected:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your AutoSize is conflicting with your Docking.

Try it without:

```
Panel panel = new Panel { AutoSize = false, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the AutoSize is "necessary". And I don't understand where is the issue for WinForms: the `Button` gets an height => the `Panel` gets this same height => Done.

Comment: @Pragmateek But your Button *doesn't* have a height — it wants to dock on the right, which requires it too get the height from the parent.  The AutoSize on the panel can't work in that scenario.

Comment: OK I see it does not work at all like the DockPanel in WPF where the DockPanel would adapt its height to the content. :/ I guess I should go with a `TableLayoutPanel`. Any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @Pragmateek A TableLayoutPanel will work, too.  You could also just anchor the controls as well.

Comment: I can't anchor as left to the Button there will be a `TextBox` but thanks for the suggestion. It works with a `TableLayoutPanel`. Thanks for your help.